Spark Parquet Error: Duplicate Columns in Nested Schema
I am attempting to create a DataFrame in Spark from a Parquet file, but when inferring the schema, I encounter the following error:
AnalysisException: Found duplicate column(s) in the data schema: `modevalid`

Upon inspecting the structure of the file, I noticed that there are two similar, but not identical, column names: MODEVALID and ModeValid_1. I don’t understand the exact reason for this error, but I am struggling to find a solution.
Creating a manual schema is not feasible because the columns inside M are highly dynamic and vary significantly. Additionally, the dataset is large. I also tried converting the M column into a StringType instead of its current StructType, but that resulted in another error.
Here is the schema structure to provide more context:
├── dynamodb
│   ├── ApproximateCreationDateTime
│   └── NewImage
│       ├── AccountEmail
│       │   └── S
│       └── DiscountData
│           └── M
│               ├── test1
│               │   └── N
│               ├── MODEVALID 
│               │   └── N
│               ├── ModeValid_1  
│               │   └── N
│               ├── test_1
│               │   └── N
│               ├── test_2
│               │   └── N
│               ├── test_3
│               │   └── N
│               └── additional_data
│                   └── P

Here is the part of the code I am using to create the dataframe:
df_disscountcoderule = spark.read \
    .schema(schema_disscountcoderule) \
    .option("mergeSchema", "true") \
    .option("recursiveFileLookup", "true") \
    .parquet(f"s3://{source_bucket}/{source_discountcodesrules_prefix}") \
    .filter(input_file_name().endswith(".parquet")) \
    .filter(~input_file_name().contains("processing-failed"))

I've tried also  enabling case sensitivity, but nothing seems to work. Could someone help me resolve this issue?"

You are already passing a schema in as an argument.  If you are reading from parquet files, the files have the schema already, have you tried without the schema argument?

you mentioned about enabling case senstivity, by default it is enabled, we need to disable it so that it treats the column differently.
can you try to disable it and check :
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.caseSensitive", "false")
